# How can i launch the GIMP command line from a Python script?

Tags: python, gimp

From this stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443...mmand-line, I have extracted this command line:

```
gimp-console -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import batch;batch.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

It works perfectly well.

Now, I would like to run this command from a Python script, usually I use `subprocess.Popen` but this time it does not work and I get this message:

```
"batch command experienced an execution error"
```

How can I launch the GIMP command line from a Python script?

Comment: Show *how* you tried to use `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to resolve this is to just put your GIMP startup script into a bash script, say `startgimp.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#set your path to GIMP or cd into the folder where you installed GIMP
gimp-console -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import batch;batch.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

then from Python simply call the bash script like so

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["bash","/path/to/your/script/startgimp.sh"])
```

If you are able to make the .sh script executable, e.g. `chmod +x startgimp.sh` then you can skip the bash part and just do `subprocess.call("/path/to/your/script/startgimp.sh")`

Some caveats

- This is assuming you're on a UNIX based system
- I used subprocess.call so this WILL block while waiting for GIMP to complete. Use Popen like you've used if you don't want this
- I don't have GIMP to try this out, but you could also try splitting your GIMP command into elements in the list and pass it to subprocess and see if that works.

e.g. `subprocess.call(["gimp-console","-idf","--batch-interpreter","python-fu-eval" and so on)`